# How to use require JS with TypeScript bundled output

Tags: typescript, requirejs

I am using `--outFile build.js -m amd` with TypeScript. This gives me a nice file full of `define` statements.

Now, how do I go about loading and using those modules with requirejs in the browser?

My test file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.22.0.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.22.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" data-main="../build" src="../lib/require.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="player.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm loading requirejs, which is loading up the build file. That includes all my modules in `define` statements like:

```
define("player", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var defaultAge = 0;
    var Player = {
        get name() {
            return "Ronald";
        },
        get age() {
            return defaultAge + 3;
        }
    };
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.default = Player;
});
```

Then in `test.js` I try and use them:

```
require(['player'], function(player){

    QUnit.test("Player name", function(assert) {
      assert.equal(Player.name, "Ronald", "Players name is set.");
    })

    QUnit.test("Player age", function(assert) {
        assert.equal(Player.age, 8, "Players age is set.");
    });   
})
```

But this throws an error, as requirejs tried to load some `player.js` – I want it to use the already defined player module.

Answer (score 2):

> as requirejs tried to load some player.js

That will *only* happen if the code `define("player", ["require", "exports"]` hasn't executed in the current context. R.js is supposed to order the code to make sure that the `define` happens before the `require`.

That said you shouldn't be writing these define/require statements yourself. If you use TypeScript *modules* you can compile to amd : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

## More

RequireJS is *old*. Please look at webpack : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: I was trying to avoid yet another tool. Hoping that tsc --outFile would do all the bundling for me. I guess web pack is still the best bet for now. Thanks!